# creating a vector from a matrix

Tags: r, cat

I have an 8 by 3 matrix like this:

```
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 2
3 1 2 1
4 1 2 2
5 2 1 1
6 2 1 2
7 2 2 1
8 2 2 2
```

I want to create a column vector from this matrix like this:

```
cell
111
112
121
122
211
212
221
222
```

This means converting all the 3 columns into a single column. How can I do this? what are the codes?

Comment: Numeric would be better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
data.frame(cell = as.integer(do.call(paste0, df1)))
```

-output

```
#  cell
#1  111
#2  112
#3  121
#4  122
#5  211
#6  212
#7  221
#8  222
```

NOTE: In the reproducible example, we used `data.frame` as input.  If it is a `matrix`, convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame` and apply the same code

---

Or use `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
unite(df1, cell, everything(), sep="") %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), B = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), C = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use matrix multiplication as follows:

```
m %*% 10^(2:0)
```

giving:

```
  [,1]
1  111
2  112
3  121
4  122
5  211
6  212
7  221
8  222
```

### Note

`m` in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 2
3 1 2 1
4 1 2 2
5 2 1 1
6 2 1 2
7 2 2 1
8 2 2 2"
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines))
```

Comment: why do you use 10^(2:0)?

Comment: It gives c(100,10,1) without writing it out.